# Count how many customers that they just have 1 order in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL database server. My query is:

> Count how many customers that they just have 1 order and how many customers that they have more than 1 orders.

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT((SELECT 
            customer_code
        FROM
            customer AS c
                LEFT JOIN
            order_info AS oi ON (c.customer_code = oi.customer_code)
        GROUP BY customer_code
        HAVING COUNT(id_order) = 1)) AS New_customers
```

How can I get this result.

Comment: Use `COUNT(id_order) >= 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grouping by `customer_code` before counting, I think this will group the rows together thus effectively removing all orders from the resultset. `HAVING` will always use the result set as the 'data feed'.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT customer_code)
FROM
    customer AS c
LEFT JOIN order_info AS oi ON (c.customer_code = oi.customer_code)

HAVING COUNT(id_order) = 1
```

OR a lot simpler (but perhaps not more efficient)

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(customer_code)
FROM
    customer AS c
WHERE (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM `order_info` 
    WHERE 
        `customer_code` = `c`.`customer_code`
) = 1
```

To get the number of customers with more than one order, simply change the `=` into `>` where appropiate.

Comment: Thank you so much. the seconds SQL query is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
count(customer_code)
FROM
customer AS c
LEFT JOIN
order_info AS oi ON (c.customer_code = oi.customer_code)
GROUP BY customer_code
HAVING COUNT(id_order) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your SQL query will return list of customer while I want to to count "list customer" in your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
For customers having 1 order

SELECT count(customer_code) FROM customer AS c
INNER JOIN order_info AS oi ON (c.customer_code = oi.customer_code)
GROUP BY customer_code HAVING COUNT(id_order) = 1))


 For customers having MORE THAn 1 order

SELECT count(customer_code) FROM customer AS c
INNER JOIN order_info AS oi ON (c.customer_code = oi.customer_code)
GROUP BY customer_code HAVING COUNT(id_order) > 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Your queries and my query have the same error. "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
count(*)
FROM
customer AS c
LEFT JOIN
order_info AS oi ON c.customer_code = oi.customer_code
HAVING COUNT(id_order) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  SELECT * FROM ( select c.customer_code, count(*) total FROM customer c
  LEFT JOIN
  order_info AS oi ON (c.customer_code = oi.customer_code) 
  GROUP BY customer_code) test
  CASE total
  WHEN 1 THEN SELECT total one_order FROM test;
  ELSE 
  SELECT total more_order FROM test
```